# Weird input buttons inside labels onClick handler behavior

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//WC3/DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html>
<body>
<label>A label
<input type="button" value="First" onClick="alert('First');" />
<input type="button" value="Second" onClick="alert('Second');" />
</label>
</body>
</html>
```

Tried this code in Firefox 3.6.8. When I click "first" it displays "first". When I click "second", it displays "second, and then "first"? Is this a weird onClick behavior due to block level tags (input) in inline tag (label)?

Answer (score 1):

Yup, it happens in alot of browsers (well all the ones i have installed anyway), and it happens with span tags (which are also inline).

If this is a form, it should read:

```
<label for="First">First</label>
<input type="button" value="First" id="First" onclick="alert('First');" />
<label for="Second">Second</label>
<input type="button" value="Second" id="Second" onclick="alert('First');" />
```

If not, try span tags instead?

Answer (score 0):

Your buttons are nested into the single `label` element. When you click on the second `button`, Firefox activates the `label` and then the first `button`. You should divide your `label`, as suggested by @jamie-wilson.